# Attention Layer changing Batch Size at inference

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, sequence

I have trained seq-to-seq model using Encoder-Decoder architecture. I'm trying to produce an output sequence given an input context, and I am trying to do that on a batch of input context vectors. I have a `Self Attention` layer before the final output in the Decoder and it seems to be changing batch shape or not getting the shape correctly, and throwing an error. It works fine if I just infer on individual sample one or a batch size of 1 but practically it will take a long in production and infer on thousands of input context vectors. So, I need your help in debugging the error and to implement a better way of producing the output sequence that is computationally optimized.

**Below is my implementation:**

```
### Define Inference Encoder
def define_inference_encoder(input_shape):
  encoder_input = Input(shape=input_shape, name='en_input_layer')

  ### First Bidirectional GRU Layer
  bidi_gru1 = Bidirectional(GRU(160, return_sequences=True), name='en_bidirect_gru1')
  gru1_out = bidi_gru1(encoder_input)

  gru1_out = Dropout(0.46598303573163413, name='bidirect_gru1_dropout')(gru1_out)

  ### Second GRU Layer
  # hp_units_2 = hp.Int('enc_lstm2', min_value=32, max_value=800, step=32)
  gru2 = GRU(hsize, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='en_gru2_layer')
  gru2_out, gru2_states = gru2(gru1_out)

  encoder_model = Model(inputs=encoder_input, outputs=[gru2_out, gru2_states])
  return encoder_model

### Define Inference Decoder
def define_inf_decoder(context_vec, input_shape):
  decoder_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
  decoder_state_input = Input(shape=(hsize,))

  de_gru1 = GRU(hsize, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='de_gru1_layer')
  de_gru1_out, de_state_out = de_gru1(decoder_input, initial_state=decoder_state_input)

  attn_layer = Attention(use_scale=True, name='attn_layer')
  attn_out = attn_layer([de_gru1_out, context_vec])

  attn_added = Concatenate(name='attn_source_concat_layer')([de_gru1_out, attn_out])

  attn_dense_layer = Dense(736, name='tanh_dense_layer', activation='tanh')

  h_hat = attn_dense_layer(attn_added)

  ### Output Layer
  preds = Dense(1, name='output_layer')(h_hat)

  decoder_model = Model(inputs=[decoder_input, decoder_state_input], outputs=[preds, de_state_out])
  return decoder_model

def set_weights(untrained_model, trained_model):
  trained_layers = [l.name for l in trained_model.layers]
  print(f"No. of trained layers: {len(trained_layers)}")

  for l in untrained_model.layers:
    if l.name in trained_layers:
      trained_wts = trained_model.get_layer(l.name).get_weights()
      if len(trained_wts)>0:
        untrained_model.get_layer(l.name).set_weights(trained_wts)
        print(f"Layer {l.name} weight set")
        
  return untrained_model
```

**Generate output sequence:**

```
inference_encoder = define_inference_encoder((12, 1))
inference_encoder = set_weights(inference_encoder, tuned_model)

for (ex_context, ex_target_in), ex_target_out in test_ds.take(1):
  print(ex_context.shape, ex_target_in.shape) ### (64, 12, 1) (64, 3, 1)

test_context, test_states = inference_encoder.predict(tf.reshape(ex_context, shape=(-1,seq_len, 1)))
print(test_context.shape, test_states.shape) ### (64, 12, 256) (64, 256)

inf_decoder = define_inf_decoder(test_context, (1,1))
inf_decoder = set_weights(inf_decoder, tuned_model)

dec_inp = tf.reshape(ex_context[:,-1], shape=(-1,1,1))
dec_inp.shape ### (64,1,1)

test_inf_decoder_out = inf_decoder.predict([dec_inp, test_states])
```

**Error:**

> ```
> ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'attn_layer' (type Attention).
>
> Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 64 for '{{node model_7/attn_layer/MatMul}} = BatchMatMulV2[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false,
> ```
>
> adj_y=true](model_7/de_gru1_layer/PartitionedCall:1, model_7/15181)'
> with input shapes: [32,1,256], [64,12,256].
>
> ```
> Call arguments received by layer 'attn_layer' (type Attention):
>   • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 1, 256), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 12, 256), >dtype=float32)']
>   • mask=None
>   • training=False
>   • return_attention_scores=False
>   • use_causal_mask=False
> ```

What I don't understand is how `attn_layer` is getting a batch size of 32 when I'm passing the inputs with the batch size of 64. It works fine when I work with the batch size of 1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing `.predict` with `predict_on_batch`. I also found out that `predict` method treat each sample individually so when passing more than one sample it creates problem for the `attention` layer as it gets more than one sample's context vector from the `encoder` to calculate the attention weights for a single sample and would be defaulting to the `batch_size` of 32 which might be causing the error when the context vector's `batch_size` is 64. So, basically changing it to `predict_on_batch` for more than one sample works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

can you print the shapes of the inputs in both configurations with batch-size 1 and bigger than one? Sometimes the problem is the order of your dimensions which you need to change.

Comment: I figured out what was the issue and have answered my question. Order of dimensions wasn't the issue. It was the method used to predict. Thank you.